# continuous and discontinuous functions

Tags: continuity

"A function which takes on infinite values throughout an interval is at least once continuous throughout a sub interval of that interval"

Prove or disprove the above statement<<<

Comment: Why should I???

Comment: Do you know any examples of everywhere discontinuous functions?

Comment: I should have been polite...I was trying to do so but I couldn't, please can you do so for me??

Comment: f(x)=x if x is irrational otherwise 0. the function is discontinuous everywhere except 0

Comment: What does "takes on infinite values throughout an interval" mean?

Comment: I second Henning's question. As written, the question is too imprecise to answer definitively.

Comment: e.g f(x)=sin x if x>0.4 otherwise 0

Comment: @TomLynd: Is that an attempt to explain what "takes on infinite values throughout an interval" means? It doesn't do that.

Comment: @Henning Makholm yes...trignometric functions are continous so how come sinx doesn't have infinite values or else you misunderstand me>

Comment: @Tom: I don't understand you at all. What does "have infinite values" mean? I don't want an example, but an understandable _definition_ of this phrase.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm sin x will have infinite values throughout the interval(-1,1) that's how its graph  is unbroken curve>..(the  completeness property of real number system)

Comment: Tom, you're still not telling us what you mean by "have infinite values". Maybe you mean, "takes on infinitely many different values". Or maybe you mean, "take on every real value between its maximum and its minimum". Or maybe you mean, "only takes on the value infinity". Or maybe you mean something else. Please try again.

Comment: I mean infinite real numbers between its max and min

Comment: There's no such thing as an infinite real number...

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: OP has deleted the comment which referred to the function taking on every real value between its minimum and its maximum, so perhaps this answer does not speak to OP's concerns. I leave it as a simple example of a nowhere-continuous bijection of a closed interval with itself. I also take the opportunity to correct a typo.]

From the comments, it seems the question is, if a function on an interval takes on every real value between its minimum and its maximum, must it be continuous somewhere on the interval?

A simple counterexample goes as follows:

Define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ by $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational; $f(x)=x+(1/2)$ is $x$ is irrational and less than $1/2$; $f(x)=x-(1/2)$ if $x$ is irrational and exceeds $1/2$.

Comment: No,the function takes just infinite values between its max and min,not every possible real number>

Comment: For the 18th and last time, the function does NOT take on "infinite values". It MAY take on infinitely many values, but every blessed one of those values is finite. AND my example takes on infinitely many values, doesn't it? But it still isn't continuous anywhere, is it? So, it answers your question, doesn't it?